# SimpleXML_Load_File returns no results for one URL, OK for another

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I have a third party service I am querying to get an XML file returned. If I visit that URL in my browser I see the XML data, but the SimpleXML_Load_File just crashes out, and I cannot get it to display any errors either.
The first DVDs URL works and loads fine, but the games one does not.

Can anyone see anything wrong with my code here, or with the XML being returned to indicate why the simplexml_load_file would just fail and prevent any more php on the page executing?

```
<?php
######DVDs
$dvdURL = 'http://dvd.find-services.co.uk/dvdSearch.aspx?sort=popular&site=sample&pagesize=1';

$dvdfeed = simplexml_load_file($dvdURL);
var_dump($dvdfeed);
echo '<hr>';
###########Games
$gameURL = 'http://game.find-services.co.uk/gameSearch.aspx?order=popular&site=sample&pagesize=1';

$gamefeed = simplexml_load_file($gameURL);
var_dump($gamefeed);
?>
```

OK, after a comment from Grim... about the code working on PHPfiddle, I have used just the code below on my server:

```
<?php
$gameURL = 'http://game.find-services.co.uk/gameSearch.aspx?order=popular&site=sample&pagesize=1';
$gamefeed = simplexml_load_file($gameURL);
var_dump($gamefeed);
?>
```

which gives an error!

> Internal Server Error
>   The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
>   Please contact the server administrator at webmaster@finditcheapest.com to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.
>   More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
>   Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

However, visiting the error log in my cPanel shows no entries. Any ideas?

@Grim... suggested using cURL, so here is the new code:

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://game.find-services.co.uk/gameSearch.aspx?order=popular&site=sample&pagesize=1");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$xml = curl_exec($ch);
$xml = utf8_encode($xml);
var_dump($xml);
$simpleXml = simplexml_load_string($xml);
var_dump($simpleXml);
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

The second var_dump is still blank, and the first gives:

> string(541) "B00ZG1S834ps4PlayStation 446927No Mans Sky11148490"

with a view source showing:

```
string(541) "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" standalone="yes"?><games><game><id>B00ZG1S834</id><platform>ps4</platform><platformName>PlayStation 4</platformName><category><![CDATA[Strategy]]></category><title><![CDATA[No Man's Sky (PS4)]]></title><titleRefNo>46927</titleRefNo><groupTitle>No Mans Sky</groupTitle></game><ResultsInfo><Message></Message><SearchString></SearchString><SearchPlatform></SearchPlatform><Page>1</Page><PageSize>1</PageSize><MoreResultsAvailable>1</MoreResultsAvailable><RowCount>48490</RowCount></ResultsInfo></games>"
```

Comment: Throwing a copy of your code onto phpfiddle shows it working correctly. Is there any more code that you've removed before you posted?

Comment: Hi Grim..., No it was that exact code that I stripped down as a minimum use case. I guess this is a problem with my server then. Any ideas as to how to investigate?

Comment: I might have found the problem (hard to say without testing it). I'm not sure why it works on phpfiddle, maybe a different server setting or PHP version.

Comment: I will raise a support ticket with my host.

Comment: My host has now upgraded the version of PHP to slightly higher than that on PHP Fiddle.
I have also contacted the provider of the feeds to see if they can change the encoding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of months later it turns out that this was simple. From the original code, I have changed the line:

```
$dvdfeed = simplexml_load_file($dvdURL);
```

to:

```
$dvds= GetPage($dvdfeed );
$dvdfeed = @simplexml_load_string($dvds);
```

where `GetPage()` is a PHP function as follows:

```
function GetPage ($URL, $PostParams = ''){
// Set params...
$ch = curl_init($URL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 100);
if ($PostParams <> ''){
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $PostParams);
};
$Page = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
return $Page;
};
```

This now loads and parses the XML correctly, regardless of the encoding.

Answer (score 2):

The latter URL (game.find-services...) is encoded with ISO-8859-1, but PHP requires UTF-8. It would be best to load the file with `CURL`, convert it to UTF-8 with `utf8_encode` then use `simplexml_load_string` to get to your data.

Comment: OK, so I changed it to
`<?php
// create a new cURL resource
$ch = curl_init();

// set URL and other appropriate options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://game.find-services.co.uk/gameSearch.aspx?order=popular&site=sample&pagesize=1");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$xml = curl_exec($ch);
$xml = utf8_encode($xml);
$simpleXml = simplexml_load_string($xml);
var_dump($simpleXml);
curl_close($ch);
?>`

and it works on PHPfiddle but not on my server (blank page only).

Comment: What do you get it you dump the contents of `$xml` to the screen and comment out the `simplexml_load_string` line?

Comment: PHPFiddle has a higher version of PHP than my host, so I will ask my host for whether this should make a difference.

Comment: If I dump out $xml before trying to make it a simplexml object I get the contents as expected, which originally made me think it was a problem with the XML coming back.